# How to write middlewares effectively in MVC structured Node app

Tags: node.js, api, express, routes, mern

I am building a node app which uses MVC structure. As i don't have experience with MVC structure i am having trouble as where to place my middlewares in this architecture effectively. **Structure overview:-**

```
//User routes
router.get('/fetchAllCourses/:schoolId', courseController.apiFetchCourses);

//Controller 
const courseServices = require('../services/courseService');

const courseCtrl = {};

courseCtrl.apiFetchCourses = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const schoolId = req.params.schoolId;
        const fetchedCourses = await courseServices.fetchCourses(schoolId);
        !fetchedCourses ? res.status(404).send('School fetch error') : 
res.send(fetchedCourses);
     } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('some error occured,' + error.message);
     }
}

module.exprots = courseCtrl;

//services
const courses = require('../models/Course'),
const courseService = {};

courseService.fetchCourses = async (schoolId) => {
    try {
        const foundSchool = await schools.findById(schoolId).populate('course');
        if (!foundSchool) return console.log('School search error');
        return foundSchool.course;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Course fetch error:  ${error}`)
    }
};

module.exports = courseServices;
```

I have a middleware which verifies the authentication token coming from client side and after verification it passes the request body to controller. But i am having trouble as where to place my middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Each controller has a router. So, middlewares should go into the router on which the controller's functions are mounted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).